# Trouble logging in to meta using https everywhere - recent change?

Tags: bug

I don't know whether something's changed here or in https everywhere (for firefox) but I now have to turn it off to log in to meta, otherwise I get bounced to https.tex.stackexchange.com, and when I go back to meta.tex.stackexchange.com I'm still not logged in.

Once logged in I can enable it again.

I don't normally do much more than read on meta so I don't know how long it's been going on - but recent-ish.

(bug tag is speculative I admit)

Comment: Related/relevant/duplicate: [Unable to login to any SE site due to HTTPS bug](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4193/5764)

Comment: Thanks @Werner, I'll copy my Q to a comment there as this seems to be  subset of that problem

Comment: There are clearly issues with hhtps everywhere and SE: the ruleset for "stack exchange (mixed content)" (Stack-Exchange.html) says it doesn't support chat or meta. The ruleset for "Stack Exchange (partial)" -- disabled by default I think -- is called Stack-Exchange-mixedcontent.xml!  Reading the comments in source of  the former, I think it's failing on *.*.stackexchange.com.